# modeling Monte Carlo in Excel

Tags: probability-distributions, monte-carlo

this is my first post! I'm not a mathematician, so please reply in layperson's terms.

I read Douglas Hubbard's excellent book, "How To Measure Anything," in which he describes how to use Monte Carlo simulations to model the likelihood of different event outcomes in Excel.

The formula he uses is $=\text{NORMINV} (\text{RAND()}, \text{mean, (max value - min value)}/3.29)$

However, this formula assumes that outcomes occur in a standard distribution. What if my distribution is not standard?

For example, let's say I'm doing a Monte Carlo to see how much my house might sell for. The max expected value is $\$500,000$ and the min value is $\$400,000$. However, the likeliest outcome is not in the middle, but slightly lower -- $\$430,000$ rather than the mean of $\$450,000$, depending upon how buyers respond to repairs that are needed.

Any idea how I would model this calculation instead? Thanks!

Comment: One dollar sign is not enough. You must put another one at the end of the expression which you want to be "dollared".

Comment: @uniquesolution The numerical values were USD values; I have edited to reflect this.

Comment: @Kevin:  because dollar signs are used to indicate MathJax, you need to escape them with a backslash. To write \$400,000 you write backslash dollar 400,000

Comment: @Kevin  The currency is clearly irrelevant.

Comment: @uniquesolution It does matter in this case, as the OP wasn't trying to replicate Mathjax.

Comment: @RossMillikan I realise that, I was trying to neutralise uniquesolution's point. Thanks.

Comment: It's entirely possible that Excel can do what you need, but first you have to decide what probability distribution accurately describes the distribution you have envisioned.

Comment: Your question is basically twofold: what distribution should I use, and how should I sample from it? The first one is too general of a question to answer even with what you have given so far. In particular, it depends on whether the cutoffs are "hard" or "soft" (note that your source uses "soft" cutoffs for the normal distribution).

Comment: (Cont.) For sampling, you can imitate the technique from your source, which is to apply the quantile function for your chosen distribution to RAND(). Depending on the distribution you choose (and the software you use), there may be a more direct way. For example, for the normal distribution, a lot of software has a direct sampling method, bypassing what Excel calls NORMINV(); one common name for this is randn. In more specialized statistical software like R, there are a *lot* of such builtin sampling routines.

Answer (score 0):

RAND() creates a random number between $0$ and $1$.  It represents the value of the cumulative distribution function of your prices.  If you have a desired distribution in mind you need to come up with an expression that takes a cdf value and returns the price, so if you are given $0.3$ your respond with the price that will be too high $30\%$ of the time and too low $70\%$ of the time.  This is what NORMINV is doing for the normal distribution.  There is a discussion of the transformation method for getting your desired distribution in [Numerical Recipes](http://apps.nrbook.com/c/index.html), starting at page 288.